# Angular - Configuration is not set in the workspace

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I try to serve my Angular app with my specific configuration but Angular does not recognize it :

```sh
$ ng serve --configuration=fr
An unhandled exception occurred: Configuration 'fr' is not set in the workspace.
See "/tmp/ng-nyZPjp/angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

My angular.json :

```
"configurations": {
  "fr": {
    "aot": true,
    "outputPath": "dist/fr/",
    "i18nFile": "src/i18n/messages.fr.xlf",
    "i18nFormat": "xlf",
    "i18nLocale": "fr",
    "i18nMissingTranslation": "error",
    "baseHref": "/fr/"
  },
  "en": { 
    "aot": true,
    "outputPath": "dist/en/",
    "i18nFile": "src/i18n/messages.en.xlf",
    "i18nFormat": "xlf",
    "i18nLocale": "en",
    "i18nMissingTranslation": "error",
    "baseHref": "/en/"
  },
    ...
```

`ng serve --configuration=en` works perfectly

Comment: similar issue:[Configuration 'dev' is not set in the workspace](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67989345/12409915)

Answer (score 155, accepted):

The error you are getting is because you didn't add it to your serve browserTarget configuration:

```
"serve":{
   "fr": {
            "browserTarget": "custom-reports:build:fr"
         },
 }
```

Comment: lmao i had spelling mistake there. thnks

Comment: my issue was that for some reason my browsertarget was set to project:build:production instead of what I actually had defined in angular.json which was "prod". So I changed it to project:build:prod and it worked. I have no idea what happened there.

Answer (score 26):

In Angular 11 you need to place the `browserTarget` property inside `configurations` (which is under `serve` in `angular.json` file):

```
"serve": {
    "configurations": {
        "fr": {
            "browserTarget": "custom-reports:build:fr"
        },
    },
},
```

Answer (score 9):

I also faced the same issue,

```
An unhandled exception occurred: Configuration 'fr' is not set in the workspace.
See "/tmp/ng-nyZPjp/angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

even though I had the configurations setup in serve and build.

My `angular.json` file was like,

```
"configurations": {
  "fr": {
    "aot": true,
    "outputPath": "dist/fr/",
    "i18nFile": "src/i18n/messages.fr.xlf",
    "i18nFormat": "xlf",
    "i18nLocale": "fr",
    "i18nMissingTranslation": "error",
    "baseHref": "/fr/"
  },
  "en": { 
    "aot": true,
    "outputPath": "dist/en/",
    "i18nFile": "src/i18n/messages.en.xlf",
    "i18nFormat": "xlf",
    "i18nLocale": "en",
    "i18nMissingTranslation": "error",
    "baseHref": "/en/"
  },
  .
  .
  .
  .
  .
  .
  .
  .
  "serve": {
    "configurations": {
        "en": {
            "browserTarget": "custom-reports:build:en"
        },
        "fr": {
            "browserTarget": "custom-reports:build:fr"
        }
    },
},
```

and I still got issue.

I solved it by changing the order of the configuration and it was solved.

my `angular.json` after change

```
"configurations": {
  "en": { 
    "aot": true,
    "outputPath": "dist/en/",
    "i18nFile": "src/i18n/messages.en.xlf",
    "i18nFormat": "xlf",
    "i18nLocale": "en",
    "i18nMissingTranslation": "error",
    "baseHref": "/en/"
  },
  "fr": {
    "aot": true,
    "outputPath": "dist/fr/",
    "i18nFile": "src/i18n/messages.fr.xlf",
    "i18nFormat": "xlf",
    "i18nLocale": "fr",
    "i18nMissingTranslation": "error",
    "baseHref": "/fr/"
  },
  .
  .
  .
  .
  .
  .
  .
  .
  "serve": {
    "configurations": {
        "en": {
            "browserTarget": "custom-reports:build:en"
        },
        "fr": {
            "browserTarget": "custom-reports:build:fr"
        }
    },
},
```

and this worked for me.

Comment: Holy crap, you're right !

Comment: @stilgar holy crap, you're right! he's right!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error in the Angular with Angular Universal V 12.x and following codes in the Angular.json file fix my error(replace serve-ssr section with the following codes):

```
"serve-ssr": {
    "builder": "@nguniversal/builders:ssr-dev-server",
    "options": {
            "browserTarget": "yourAppName:build",
            "serverTarget": "yourAppName:server"
     },
     "configurations": {
            "production": {
                 "browserTarget": "yourAppName:build:production",
                 "serverTarget": "yourAppName:server:production"
            }
     }
}
```

[Github](https://github.com/angular/universal/issues/2158)