# An unhandled exception occurred: Configuration 'dev' is not set in the workspace

Tags: angular, configuration

I started to publish my Angular app. But I can't fix this error. I deployed in Azure. Add this looking easy. I think that the problem is in `angular.json`. Firstly I tried to update every dependency in `package.json`

Where is the wrong in this config file?

```
    {
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "ODZ.Web": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {},
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "progress": false,
            "extractCss": false,
            "outputPath": "dist",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome.scss",
              "node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/solid.scss",
              "node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/regular.scss",
              "node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/brands.scss",
              "node_modules/angular-bootstrap-md/assets/scss/bootstrap/bootstrap.scss",
              "node_modules/angular-bootstrap-md/assets/scss/mdb.scss",
              "node_modules/animate.css/animate.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.js",
              "node_modules/hammerjs/hammer.min.js"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "ODZ.Web:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "ODZ.Web:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "ODZ.Web:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "assets": [
              "src/assets"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "server": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:server",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist-server",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.server.json"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "ODZ.Web-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e/",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "ODZ.Web:serve"
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "ODZ.Web:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "ODZ.Web"
}
```

I tried to fix this, but when I execute `npm build --prod`... I changed every dependency in my project, but didn't help. If someone is fixing this error. Bro, pleas help! Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular - Configuration is not set in the workspace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58876170/angular-configuration-is-not-set-in-the-workspace)

Answer (score 3):

En "serve" angular.json agregar `"options": { "browserTarget": "gox-sistema:build" },`

Quedaria algo asi:

```js
"serve": {
  "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
  "options": {
    "browserTarget": "nombreApp:build"
  },
  "configurations": {
    "production": {
      "browserTarget": "nombreApp:build:production"
    },
    "development": {
      "browserTarget": "nombreApp:build:development"
    }
  }
},
```

Comment: this worked for me thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar error when I ran the build command as below:

```
ng build --configuration=DEV --crossOrigin=anonymous
```

In Jenkins:

```
An unhandled exception occurred: Configuration 'DEV' is not set in the workspace.
```

In log file:

```
Log filename: /tmp/ng-W1hy24/angular-errors.log 

[error] Error: Configuration 'DEV' is not set in the workspace.
```

I believe below are two reasons causing the issue in the angular.json file.

1. JSON is case sensitive so use both field names the same.
2. angular.json missing the configuration for DEV.

Check if you are missing the configuration for DEV, add something similar below.

code sample:

```
"DEV": {

             "fileReplacements": [

               {

                 "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",

                 "with": "src/environments/environment.dev.ts"

               }

             ],

             "optimization": true,

             "outputHashing": "all",

             "sourceMap": false,

             "extractCss": true,

             "namedChunks": false,

             "aot": true,

             "extractLicenses": true,

             "vendorChunk": false,

             "buildOptimizer": true,

             "budgets": [

               {

                 "type": "initial",

                 "maximumWarning": "4mb",

                 "maximumError": "6mb"

               }

             ],

             "serviceWorker": true,

             "ngswConfigPath": "ngsw-config.json"
```

Comment: did not work , Anguar 11